# sorted map implementation (ValueComparableMap), sorting not maintained when calling Map.Entry setValue

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, treemap

I've used solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420912/664690) which describes how to implement a value comparable map in java, and it is working fine for the put method, however, when I try to modify values already in the map through the `Map.Entry` type, sorting is no longer maintained. Following code exhibits the issue:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Float> valCompMap = new ValueComparableMap<Integer, Float>(Ordering.natural());
// some code that puts entries in map
Random random = new Random();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> e : valCompMap.entrySet()) {
  e.setValue(e.getValue() + random.nextFloat());
}
//parse keys into list
List<Integer> sorted_keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(valCompMap.keySet()); //here sorted_keys are not sorted according to values in original key value pair in the map
```

As a work around, I'm re-putting keys with new values as such:

```
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(valCompMap.keySet());
for (Integer k : keys) {
  valCompMap.put(k, valCompMap.get(k) + random.nextFloat());
}
```

Problems with work around:

1. Not straight forward (doesn't express intent clearly)
2. Seem to be in-efficient since looking at the `put` method in `ValueComparableMap`, it involves branching, searching, removing and 2x putting.

So what would be an efficient way to modify a value in such `ValueComparableMap` (while maintaining the live sort property)?

Here is a simple test to demonstrate issue:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Float> valCompMap = new ValueComparableMap<Integer, Float>(Ordering.natural());

//populate map with random stuff
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  valCompMap.put(i, random.nextFloat());
}

//print
System.out.println("Before modifying, map:");
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> e : valCompMap.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
}

//modify values in map
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> e : valCompMap.entrySet()) {
  e.setValue(e.getValue() + random.nextFloat());
}

//print
System.out.println("After modifying, map:");
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> e : valCompMap.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
}

//modify values in work-around way
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(valCompMap.keySet());
for (Integer k : keys) {
  valCompMap.put(k, valCompMap.get(k) + random.nextFloat());
}

//print
System.out.println("After modifying using work-around, map:");
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> e : valCompMap.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Before modifying, map:
6=0.05478877
4=0.07464349
1=0.08668131
2=0.0869472
3=0.32622492
8=0.35595274
5=0.3879655
9=0.602066
7=0.7913183
0=0.8479772

After medifying, map:
6=0.9277618
4=0.9426463
1=0.269701
2=0.95250356
3=0.8576952
8=0.547724
5=1.1656129
9=1.3945209
7=1.0475534
0=0.91609937

After modifying using work-around, map:
3=0.96215
6=1.036502
4=1.1082084
1=1.1496286
8=1.2940607
7=1.343531
0=1.4778173
2=1.6039091
5=1.6165544
9=2.1403322
```

Comment: How _could_ this ever work?? A `TreeMap` doesn't check your entities for changes and rearrange them, even without adding the sorting by value complication. You **must** remove the element from the `Map`, change it, then reinsert it.

Comment: I presume you mean `Map.Entry` rather than `Map.Entity`?

Comment: @Edd, you're right, just edited question, thanks for pointing that out. Notice that it's written correctly inside code snippets.

Comment: @BoristheSpider does your comment still apply after the edit? If so, then I'm not quite sure I understand what you said. I'm new to java and I'm trying to learn something here.

Comment: My comment is about the _contract_ for a `TreeMap`. You simply **must** not change any data that is used in the sorting whilst it is in the `Map`.